# Remove Virtualmin Access via IP

Tags: webmin, virtualmin

I'm trying to harden server security by following suggestions given by securityscorecard.com. I can access Webmin / Virtualmin via the IP directly with:

https://[my-**ip**]:10000

It does so with a self-signed SSL cert and the securityscorecard service does not like it.

I have a domain cert and can also, preferably, access Virtualmin like:

https://[my-**domain**]:10000

**How can I disable access via https://[my-ip]:10000?** Redirect to domain?

OR

How can I somehow assign a valid (not self-signed) cert to this?